# Whether select field list and group by field list be in sync in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have noticed that in select field whatever is given needs to be added in the group by clause.

for ex:    `select * from tablename group by column1,column2.....`

But I have a query here which works fine without having all select fields being present in group by clause.
The query selects all client names who have more than one sales order by joining client_master that stores client details and sales_order that stores order details.

```
select client_master.client_name 
from client_master 
join sales_order on client_master.clientno=sales_order.clientno 
group by client_master.clientno 
having count(sales_order.clientno)>1
```

here my select field has client_master.client_name but my group by clause doesn't have any client_master.client_name still it works fine but while selecting from single table it throws error if select fields are not present in group by clause.
It seems confusing.

Regards

Comment: Is client_master.clientno your primary key for this table? Please check the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY

Comment: It's still a good idea to stick to the old GROUP BY rule:
"If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." (Who knows, some day the primary key is changed or removed...)